# Matching a series of strings to a specific image in a series with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, if-statement

I am trying to call a specific image if a string of text is matched. Is there a way to make sure the value of myArray1 produces a specific value from myArray2 everytime myArray1 is used?

```
$('div').each(function() {
   var myArray1 = [ "word1", "word2" ];
   var myArray2 = [ "img1.jpg", "img2.jpg" ];
        if($('div.condition').text().indexOf(' myArray1 ') != -1 )
          $('div.img').css({'background-image':'url(' + myArray2 + ')'});
        else if($('div.condition').text().indexOf(' myArray1 ') != -1 )
          $('div.img').css({'background-image':'url(' + myArray2 + ')'});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J3tyT/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy fix

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if($('div.condition').text().indexOf('SOMEWORD') > -1 )
      $('div.img').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.listofimages.com/someimage.jpg")'});
    else if($('div.condition').text().indexOf('ANOTHERWORD') > -1 )
      $('div.img').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.listofimages.com/another.jpg")'});
```

Use > rather than !=

Comment: I might not have formatted my question correctly. I was wondering if there was some way to prevent myself from writing hundred of 'else if statements'.

I'll see if I can properly word it.

Comment: Ah I dont believe there is unfortunately, but if your looking at doing a bunch of these you could make a function that just hold them all, then just call the function from your .each.